# Request Timeout in Azure Cosmos DB in sdk v3

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am inserting the data to azure cosmos db. In some time it throws an error (Request Timeout : 408). I have increased the Request Timeout to 10 mins.

Also, i have iterate each item from api and calling `CreateItemAsync()` method instead of bulk executor.

Data To Insert = 430 K Items
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos SDK used = v3
Container Throughput = 400

Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just increase your throughput. But it's going to cost you *a lot* of money if you leave it increased. 400 RU/s isn't going to cut it unless you batch your operation to the point where it's going to take a long time to insert 400k items.

If this is a one-time deal, increase your RU/s to 2000+, then start slowly inserting items. I would say, depending on the size of your documents, maybe do 50 at a time, then wait 250 milliseconds, then do 50 more until you are done. You will have to play with this though.

Once you are done, move your RU/s back down to 400.

Cosmos DB can be ridiculously expensive, so be careful.

---

**ETA:**

This is from [some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data):

***Increase throughput:** The duration of your data migration depends on the amount of throughput you set up for an individual collection or a set of collections. Be sure to increase the throughput for larger data migrations. After you've completed the migration, decrease the throughput to save costs. For more information about increasing throughput in the Azure portal, see performance levels and pricing tiers in Azure Cosmos DB.*

Comment: Thank u for your Answer @Andy.Is there any other way instead of increasing Throughput or some optimization in the code

Comment: Yes. Like I said: don’t send data so fast.

Comment: Bulk is a throughput optimized mode which aims at pushing the data as fast as possible and try and use all available throughput. What Andy says is valid, the volume of data you want to push through is really high compared to your provisioned throughput. Assuming 1 item takes 5 RU/s to be saved, 400 RU/s allows for 80 items per second roughly. Either reduce the volume, increase the provisioned RU/s, or expect the whole operation to take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation page for 408 timeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-dot-net-sdk-request-timeout) lists a number of possible causes to investigate.

Aside from addressing the root cause with the SDK client app or increasing throughput, you might also consider leveraging Azure Data Factory to ingest the data as [in this example](https://cosmosdb.github.io/labs/dotnet/labs/02-load_data_with_adf.html). This assumes your data load is an initialization process and your data can be made available as a blob file.